# Can't Change Height of Label Using Autolayout

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout, interface-builder

Currently I have a label located at the very top of my screen. I have constrained it to both sides and the top. Everything is fine. However, I can't change the height of the label without it telling me that the expected height of 20 has changed. In fact, I can't set the height of the label to any constant without getting a layout error. Here is what my situation looks like and here is the error. Somebody please help. [image: situation][image: error]

Comment: when you control drag from your label to your label. You can set its height as fixed value

Comment: I tried that. Only the width showed up. But thanks for trying.

Comment: have you tried from constraint bar ?

Comment: I tried that and it works. However, then I get a warning that won't go away. The warning is above in the image I posted.

Comment: The height constraint didn't appear because you are control dragging horizontally. Try dragging vertically from bottom to top or top to bottom then the height constraint would definitely appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `Height` constraint to your `label` or bottom constraint to the next element. All other options will give you an error. You can do it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is `UILabel` the only `UI` Object on your screen?
Secondly If you don't want to set height of `UILabel` increase its `Font` size because `UILabel` height calculated according to its `Font` size.

Comment: Thanks the font thing worked. But that still didn't technically solve the problem. And please rephrase you question.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you didn't give the `height/width` constraint to the `UILabel` then `x-code`  determine its `height/width` by the inside content.

Same in your case you didn't give the height constraint to the `UILabel`. Now system needs minimum `height = 20` to set the Label content. If you want height according to your need then give it `height constraint`.

Comment: Thank you, but I get that. The problem is I have already tried to set the height to a constant. It didn't work though,.

Comment: Obviously it work. Post your all constraints regarding to this label, let me chechk

Comment: All the constraints are shown in the image. And my height is set to 627 in the side bar. That's pretty much it